# Can you take Martial Training multiple times to gain multiple martial disciplines?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

In Pathfinder, can you gain more than one martial discipline at the same time by just taking the Martial Training feat twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Not from Martial Training.

You cannot gain more than one martial discipline by taking the Martial Training 1 feat twice, because you can only take the Martial Training 1 feat once.

First, note an example feat, [Skill Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/skill-focus-final/), which contains this text:

> **Special:** You can gain this feat multiple times. Its effects do not stack. Each time you take the feat, it applies to a new skill.

The [Martial Training 1](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/martial-training-i-combat/) feat does not say you can take it multiple times, therefore you can only take that feat once. Martial Training 2 and the rest of the chain grant you additional maneuvers from the chosen discipline, not access to a new discipline.